# How to "Inflate" (like in rectangle) or scale a hexagon

Tags: c#, math, matrix, graphics

I'm currently working a project with a grid filled with hexagons. Every hexagon has the exact same size and I'm painting a border for every of them.

Comment: Post your drawing code.

Comment: Here is some code, but I'd love to know if it's possible to use a Matrix to apply this effect.

Comment: this should [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformpoints?view=netframework-4.8) - Note that the sacling transformation with apply a multiplication, so you can't 'add 1' as this makes little or no sense. An a Translation will add some number but only the same to all points. So to 'inflate' you need to translate to the center and then scale. .!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to the problem. Let's have a a simplistic one first:

- You can create the hexagon in the right size and location from the start. This is simple, at least if you want symmetric polygons.

Let's see:

```
List<PointF> Polygon(PointF center, int count, float radius, float angle)
{
    List<PointF> pts = new List<PointF>();
    for (float i = angle; i < 360; i+= 360f/count)
    {
        float rad = (float)(Math.PI / 180 * i);
        pts.Add(new PointF(center.X + (float)Math.Sin(rad) * radius,
                            center.Y + (float)Math.Cos(rad) * radius));
    }
    return pts;
}
```

This allows you to pick the center location, the symmetry, the size and a starting angle. To get a hexagon pointed upwards at `(99,99)` with a height of `160` use this call:

```
List<PointF> points = Polygon(new PointF(99, 99), 6, 80, 0);
```

- Or you can transform a given polygon. For this you can use any polygon (or any set of points), but it is up to you to define the center of the figure and calculate the needed scaling factor.

To use a factor of `1.25f` for both axes and translate by (40, 10) use this:

```
var points2 = points.ToArray();  // create a copy
using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
{
    m.Scale(1.25f, 1.25f, MatrixOrder.Append);
    m.Translate(40, 10, MatrixOrder.Append);
    m.TransformPoints(points2);
}
```

Result:

[image: hexagons]

Note that to create a regular grid you will probably get away with less code using the 1st method..

Let's draw a grid of hexagons:

```
int r = 80;
float w = (float)(Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * 60) * r);
float h = (float)(Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * 60) * r);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, (r * 2  + h * 2)  * i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(w * 2, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Green, points.ToArray());
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(w, r + h);
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Green, points.ToArray());
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-w, -r- h );
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: hex-grid]

Comment: Hi TaW. I'm currently good with the grid of hexagons and whenever the application size change, I compute the highest radius of a hexagon so that the grid fit the windows. All I wanted is an example of a matrix that downscale a hexagon so that it perfectly fit within the given points. That said, the way you genererate hexagon is better than mine, so I'm gonna use your. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work with a matrix, you would have to construct a matrix from the identity matrix X a translate matrix to move the center of the polygon to the origin (0, 0) X a scale matrix to scale the coordinates slightly smaller (or larger) based on a ratio  X a translate matrix to move the coordinates back to where they were before they started.   You could then apply the resulting matrix to each of your coordinates (as vectors) and they would each get transformed.

The matrix is useful if you have many of the same transforms to run against a large number of coordinates, because you calculate the matrix once and quickly apply it to many vectors.  In the case, you only have 6 vectors (coordinates), so it won't save you much.  Your approach of adding integers to coordinates will run faster, and provided you encapsulating that it a nicely named and reusable method e.g. `GetInlayPolygonForTile()` it would be plenty readable.

Comment: You can apply a Matrix to the Graphics object or to the GraphicsPath object. A Scale and a Transform Matrix, here. Or a Matrix with a Scale transformation applied to the GraphicsPath and then `TranslateTransform` the Graphics object. There's no need to apply it to each vector. Of course, the Scale is a ratio, so the coordinate transformation must apply the same ratio to the origin vector *backwards*.

Comment: Tim & Jimi thanks for your answer. Sure I could make a static method GetInlayPolygonForTile(), but since it is a beta, I'm focusing of making it work rather than optimizing the code (kinda spent 3/4H trying to achieve it with a matrix and transform. That said, point taken. If you think for a single hexagon it would run faster to tweak 6 coordinates I could just keep my code. Yet, for my knowlegde I'll keep trying on tomorrow with Matrix. In this project, performance doesn't really matter since the grid is small, but I'd love to learn how it achieve in case I need in the future ! Thanks again!

Comment: @Tim the 1st part of your answer is correct imo, but the 2nd part is not. It will certainly pay off to write a function that does the job and can be reused. The calulation needed to find the center is trivial (given we know the polygon) and for the scaling there isn't really anything to calculate.

Comment: @TaW yes and learning how to achieve something you're not capable of doing is always good thing ! Thanks for your help and explainations :)